# How can I extract entities from a query in java?

Tags: java, information-retrieval, named-entity-extraction

I've found [Pingar](http://apidemo.pingar.com/Entities.aspx) and [ANNIE](http://services.gate.ac.uk/annie/) but none of them worked to me when submitting queries. It seems like they need an entire document to extract entities, when I remove a certain amount of words it stops detecting locations and people and classifying them only as keywords. I just need to detect georeferences and personal names.

Thank you!

Comment: Do you think it'll work with queries? I'll try it, thank you!